# crear cupon en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

alguien sabe como crear un cupón en laravel tengo la siguiente tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si es tipo cupon relleno el campo cupon para darle una clave, pero quisiera saber si a traves de un input en una vista se podria escribir el codigo y poder utilizarlo osea consultar si el registro existe me ponga si existe y si no me diga intentalo de nuevo, no se como hacer algo asi =(

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado?

Comment: Deberías mostrar parte del código que tienes para que obtengas ayuda. Revisa [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la logica tiene que ir en el controlador, usa validacion de laravel que es muy facil

podes hacer un metodo

te dejo un ejemplo de la idea

```
public function update(Request $request, tuModelo $modelo){
    $request->validate([
    'tuInput' => 'in:db.tabla.col'
])
   $modelo->cupon = $request->cupon;
   $modelo->save();
}
```